# Image not correctly positioned in the screen in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Am new to andengine. Am trying to implement the game controller image in the screen. Am following the andengine examples. But the image is broken and appeared in the corner of the screen in a shape of triangle. Please Help. My code as follows.....................

```
public class ExtremeGame extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

private Camera mCamera;

private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private TextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;

private BitmapTextureAtlas mOnScreenControlTexture;
private TextureRegion mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion;
private TextureRegion mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion;

private DigitalOnScreenControl mDigitalOnScreenControl;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
     BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

     this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(null, 32, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
     this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_box.png", 0, 0);

     this.mOnScreenControlTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(null, 256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
     this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this, "onscreen_control_base.png", 0, 0);
     this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this, "onscreen_control_knob.png", 128, 0);

     this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mOnScreenControlTexture);


}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene();

    final int centerX = (int) ((CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2);
    final int centerY = (int) ((CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2);
    final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, mFaceTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(face);
    face.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);

    scene.attachChild(face);


    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.5f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScaleCenter(0, 128);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScale(1.25f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setScale(1.25f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();

    scene.setChildScene(this.mDigitalOnScreenControl);

    return scene;
}



 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends what andengine branch you are using, gles2 or gles2 Anchor Center.

The main, most significant change in the GLES2 Anchor Center is that the coordinate system has changed. The coordinate system in the GLES2 Anchor Center branch has its origin in the lower left, this was changed for multiple reasons.

To understand how does new coordinate system works, see article posted on my blog.

http://www.matim-dev.com/gles2-anchor-center.html